# I'm making weightSum but it can't be sorted

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to sort an image and a text but it's not working.

Here is the picture:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:weightSum="100" >

          <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="80"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:src="@drawable/image" />

          <Button
                  android:id="@+id/blah"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="20"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:text="Blah blah blah blah"
                  android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you want? what's you current effect?

Comment: It's on the URL that I poster, the brown image comes out a little high in the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

to both your ImageView and your Button, that will give you the alignment you depicted in your image.

```
<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="100" >

      <ImageView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="80"
              android:gravity="right"
              android:src="@drawable/image" />

      <Button
              android:id="@+id/blah"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="20"
              android:gravity="left"
              android:text="Blah blah blah blah"
              android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also you didn't set the height for your button.

Answer (score 0):

If I got correctly what you want to achieve you can try this:

```
 android:id="@+id/blah"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="20"
 android:gravity="left|center"
 android:text="Blah blah blah blah"
 android:textSize="15sp" />
```

The change is `gravity="left|center"`